# An internal error has ocurred - MSTSC Crashes

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop-services, mstsc

In brief: I cannot Remote desktop a particular server - say "X" from "A" server, but with MSTSC /ADMIN switch I was able to RD "X" server. But the same "X" server can be RD'd from "B" server even without ADMIN Switch.

All servers are 2012 R2 DataCenter

I am getting this weird error - An internal error has occurred, while trying to MSTSC. I was trying to remote desktop to a server from one of our servers that has connectivity allowed. All required Ports are allowed and I was able to Remote desktop to that particular server using /admin switch but not with mstsc alone. I was able to RD to other servers fine, but not to this particular server. When I try to RD it, I am getting MSTSC crash in event viewer, I get credential page and then after entering credentials I see certificate warning and then post accepting that, it says establishing connection and after few seconds it says - An internal Error has occurred. :(

I see event viewer and found Event ID 1000 -

## Below is the error log:

---

Faulting application name: mstsc.exe, version: 6.3.9600.16384, time stamp: 0x5215e2b5
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.3.9600.17278, time stamp: 0x53eebd22
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00000000000326a0
Faulting process id: 0x1d78
Faulting application start time: 0x01d0236d841ae5c5
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\system32\mstsc.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report Id: ce466ba8-8f61-11e4-80f4-002dd8150a44
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:

---

I am really worried, because I was able to RD this particular failing server from a different machine, but not from this particular server.

Any idea? Please help in this case. Let me know if further information is required.

Comment: Reboot server A and try again.

Comment: Hello @joeqwerty - I tried that, but still no luck :(

Comment: @chaladi Try copying the mstsc.exe and mstscax.dll files from another computer (maybe even with a different version), and see what happens.

Comment: Same issues here, any update on a solution. New Server 2012 R2 install. No RDP even from Win 7, all the same cert notifications and signoffs then the error.

Comment: @htm11h The issue was fixed. Identified that MTU size is the culprit. Between Source to destination server the routers are not allowing MTU size greater than 1400, in our case. So reduced the MTU size on source server to initiate traffic with less MTU size.

Comment: @htm11h 
Follow below steps...
Verify the MTU size between source to destination using "ping -f -l 1500 192.168.1.1" 

If it says:  
C:\Users\sreekanth>ping -f -l 1500 192.168.1.1

Pinging 192.168.1.1 with 1500 bytes of data:
Packet needs to be fragmented but DF set


then lower the MTU value and test again until you see ping success. Change your Source server default MTU size to that value and that will fix.

Example From CMD:
Type netsh interface ipv4 show subinterface
Type netsh interface ipv4 set subinterface “Local Area Connection” mtu=1400 store=persistent

Comment: @htm11h PPP connections use 1500 MTU size from windows servers and VPN connections use 1400. Refer: [link] (http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/826159)

Answer (score 1):

With one of our terminal servers, we rebooted it each time this happened. Today, reboot did nothing so we unjoined & re-joined to the domain to fix the issue.